# If statement is not working inside click/swipe event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use if statement inside a jquery event but it is not worknig. This is my code:

```
 $(".carousel").swipeleft(function(){

            rightPos += 242;

            $(this).animate({ "right": rightPos }, swipeSpeed);

            var currentRightPos = $(".carousel").css("right");

            alert(currentRightPos);

            if(currentRightPos > 500){

                alert("Its 500");
            };

        });
```

I dont know what is happening. If statement is not working even inside a click event. Swipe event also working fine. `alert(currentRightPos);` also working fine but only if statement is not working. I have read through 5-6 questions in stackoverflow but nothing was helpful. If you need any further information please comment. Thank You.

Comment: what is the first alert showing you ?

Comment: you should parse `currentRightPos` to an int, or the js interpreter will cast 500 to a string: `parseInt(currentRightPos, 10)`

Comment: @AndréR. Its showing right css value after swiping correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".carousel").css("right")` returns `'Npx'`.

Try with:

```
var currentRightPos = parseInt($(".carousel").css("right").replace(/px/, ''));
```

Comment: I used `N` as a number. E.g.: `'5px'` (where `N` represents the number `5` and the single quotes a String).

Answer (score 1):

It should by something like this.

```
$(".carousel").click(function(){

            var rightPos = "+=242";
            var swipeSpeed = 500;

            $(this).animate({right:rightPos},swipeSpeed);

            var currentRightPos = $(".carousel").css("right");

            alert(currentRightPos);

            if(currentRightPos > "500"){

                alert("Its 500");
            };

        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svejofck/

Hope it helps :)